# Populating a min function in php with an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have been trying to get this to work and can't.

I have a string like `pop.2,rundo.5,moti.3` and I am trying to get the `pop`, `rundo`, and `moti` into a `min` with an already populated `associative array` function.

The final result should look like or mirror,

```
$min = min($user['pop'], $user['rundo'], $user['moti']);
```

So far I have

```
$items = 'pop.2,rundo.5,moti.3';
// EXPLODE MINUS ITEMS
$minus = explode(',', $items);
// GET MINUS ITEMS AMOUNT
foreach($minus as $item) {
     $itemMinus[] = explode('.', $item);
}
```

This is as far as I got and am now stuck. I have tried several ways of doing it but to no avail.

I know I can get the values like so,

```
$itemMinus[0][0] // pop
$itemMinus[1][0] // rundo
$itemMinus[2][0] // moti
```

But I need to dynamically generate it as I could be putting in strings that have more values such as `youdo.3,gate.3,hiya.4,moti.0,yellow.2`.

Any ideas and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there. Use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/function.list.php) to get the key and value:

```
$itemsMinus = array();
$items = 'pop.2,rundo.5,moti.3';
// EXPLODE MINUS ITEMS
$minus = explode(',', $items);
// GET MINUS ITEMS AMOUNT
foreach($minus as $item) {
    // Add to the array by key
    list($key, $value) = explode(".", $item); 
    $itemsMinus[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($itemsMinus);
Array
(
    [pop] => 2
    [rundo] => 5
    [moti] => 3
)
```

Comment: Cool I will try this thanks!? Will let you know how I get on!

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to Michael post you can use [`sscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) method instead of `list` and `explode`

```
$items = 'pop.2,rundo.5,moti.3';
// EXPLODE MINUS ITEMS
$minus = explode(',', $items);
// GET MINUS ITEMS AMOUNT
foreach($minus as $item) {
    sscanf( $item,'%s.%d', $key, $value); 
    $itemsMinus[$key] = $value;
}
```